# Powershell, Excel, print area

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an Excel file with a defined print area.

If I open that file "by hand" (double click, enter) all is good.

If I open that file through Powershell, the print area is gone.

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($RG)
```

Anybody any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Assuming $RG is the full path to your workbook. It is working fine when I try it. Are you sure it is gone? Can you try Start-Process -FilePath $RG

Comment: Yup, it's gone for sure. BUT if i use the Start-Process, that one actually works fine. Why is that??